# My app web pages look like simple text when deployed to Heroku

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm deploying a rails version: 3.2.13 app using jquery-rails version: 3.0.1

The HTML pages look fine on my local machine (I use Webrick) but when I deploy the new version of my app to Heroku, all the pages look like simple text and js doesn't work anymore, although the former version I deployed looks fine.

Comment: statics files are not getting included.

Comment: and what should I do to include them ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the rails_12factor gem for your production environment?

Add

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

to your Gemfile, bundle, commit changes and push to Heroku.

Comment: Why wasn't that necessary until now ? What changed ?

Comment: I tried your recipe to no avail. My pages still look like text and js doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

the manifest.yml file in public/assets was blocking the re-deployment of the assets.

and I don't understand the comments below - that I cannot comment - because that is the complete answer to my question:

my pages were appearing as text because the manifest.yml file in public/assets was blocking the re-deployment of the assets.

And that's that.